# Can't connect to socket.io over internet, only localhost

Tags: node.js, http, ssl, tcp, socket.io

I have the following HTTP ports that I'm allowed to perform the connection:

`HTTP TCP 80/443/3128/8080`

I'm using `80` for the browser client and have no handler to allow both a browser request and socket.io at the same time so it fails with `EADRINUSE` error. All the other ports fail to connect, either with a CORS error or they simply won't. The nodejs server is running but not receiving any input (only console.logs independent of the connection) and the ports are opened. This pops out in the browser console when trying to connect `http://URL:SOCKET_PORT/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1441553166917-1` with the command `var socket = io('http://URL:SOCKET_PORT', { secure: false, "connect timeout": 5000 });` (I turn secure: true in 443 but it still fails). **I don't need the connection to run over an SSL** and I have all the necessary script includes so please don't ask about it (it works localhost).

Here is my nodejs server code:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require("http").Server(app); //or "https"
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
http.listen(socket_port, function(){ (...)
```

**So, to resume:**

- Title
- Ports: `HTTP TCP 80/443/3128/8080`
- No need for SSL
- Browser just retries to connect without no error message, only successive attempts
- Nodejs server is alive and running
- Ports are opened with TCP

What could be wrong in this scenario?

Comment: 1) I'm not really getting why you get the `EADRINUSE` error. It's on server side, right ? And you're solely running the node script ?

2) Do you bind some function on the connection event or any other event emittted by io or the socket?